# How to check if prevProps and nextProps are the same in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have such lifecycle hook

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):       

    if (prevProps.activeItems !== this.props.activeItems) {
      this.props.doAction();
    }
  }
```

and props have such a structure

```
[
  {id:1, hidden: true},
  {id:2, hidden: false}
  {id:3, hidden: true}
]
```

I need to check if property hidden is the same in prev and next props for in every object, so I will know if I need to run function in if condition or no. How can I do that?

Comment: You really can't, that is the bad part of an immutable data structure. You'll have to do the checking manually, I use `array.every`, for this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use componentWillReceiveProps -- this hook will be soon deprecated.  componentDidUpdate is the correct hook for what you need.

The problem is that the comparison you're doing is a shallow comparison -- i.e. it doesn't compare the nested values in the respective arrays.

The basic idea is that you should loop over both arrays and compared individual nested values -- here's more information about that: [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

You could also use something like's lodash's isEqual method to perform a deep comparison between two arrays: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#isEqual

Comment: I do not use omponentWillReceiveProps, I know about it. I tried isEqual and it is work for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make use of componentWillReceiveProps.

```
  componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) { 
      if(nextProps.something !== this.props.soemthing) {
           //write your statements
      }
  }
```

If you have array of object then You need to map through each object inside array by comparing old props.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops and recheck my structure, I have Array of objects and I need to check proprerty of every object

Comment: So you dont know, which property being changed ?

Comment: Hidden will be changed

Comment: You need to map through each object inside array by comparing old props.

Comment: I know this, I'm asked for some solution

Answer (score 0):

Parent component could take care of this to provide immutable `activeItems` only in case `activeItems` elements change.

Otherwise  `activeItems` arrays needs to be tested if they are shallowly equal, e.g. [with `recompose`](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#shallowequal):

```
import { shallowEqual } from 'recompose'; 

...

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (shallowEqual(prevProps.activeItems, this.props.activeItems)) {
      this.props.doAction();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use componentWillReceiveProps for now. because it is getting deprecated soon

```
   componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
       if(nextProps.something === this.props.soemthing) {
           // do your work
       }
   }
```

Comment: what typo in this answer? and look closely it is not same. thanks

Comment: no your answer completely wrong, I said that I have ARAAY OF OBJECTS and I need to check proprety of both props

Comment: Listen rick, you have Array of Objects. okay and you pass this array as a prop in this component. right. now first you have to compare old props and new props are different because whenever any prop changes it comes in "componentWillRecieveProps". let suppose you pass that array in temp named key. so 

if(nextProps.temp === this.props.temp) {

           let filteredArray = nextProps.temp.filter((tempObject) => {

                  return "check your condition here";

           })

  }